# What kind of weather conditions would produce turbulence with an intensity of 90 feet per second?

Tags: safety, weather

This is the official documentation that we found regarding current commercial airplane design criteria; https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/25.341

It says the criteria for continuous turbulence is 90 feet per second, or 'fps'. Is this a big improvement from the criteria of the 1950's and 1960's, which saw several commercial airplanes lost due to turbulence-induced structural failure?

Comment: 90fps approximates to 120kph or 75mph, so winds of that strength aren’t uncommon.  The question of turbulence is rather different because it presumably refers to a localised airspeed relative to the airframe.  Like many test criteria this is easy to set up in a wind tunnel but it’s difficult to predict what real-world atmospheric conditions would result in that rate of air movement.

Comment: Thunderstorm, bad day in the mountains, strong frontal boundary, microburst.

Answer (score 2):

90 feet per second is 5,400 feet per minute. Per [the PHAK, Chapter 12](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/phak/media/14_phak_ch12.pdf) (p.12-11), a microburst can produce those conditions:

> A typical microburst has a horizontal diameter of 1–2 miles and a
> nominal depth of 1,000 feet. The lifespan of a microburst is about
> 5–15 minutes during which time it can produce downdrafts of up to
> 6,000 feet per minute (fpm) and headwind losses of 30–90 knots,
> seriously degrading performance.